# How to render print with gWidgets in R?

Tags: r, rendering, gwidgets, shiny

I am trying to show the results summary using gWidgets, but I cannot find a widget that can do the job easily.

For example,

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2,10,20, labels=c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
```

I would like to have a window or a text box which prints `summary(lm.D9)`. like the following:

```
Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ group)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.0710 -0.4938  0.0685  0.2462  1.3690 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   5.0320     0.2202  22.850 9.55e-15 ***
groupTrt     -0.3710     0.3114  -1.191    0.249    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.6964 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.07308,    Adjusted R-squared: 0.02158 
F-statistic: 1.419 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.249
```

This can be easily done with shiny using `renderPrint` and `verbatimTextOutput`. I am hoping that there is also something in `gWidgets`.

A related question, I can use `capture.output` to write the summary into a text file. It would be helpful if there is a widget that can open the text file and show the content in the user interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gtext` and `capture.output`:

```
out <- paste(capture.output(summary(lm.D9)), collapse="\n")
w <- gwindow()
txt <- gtext(out, cont=w, font.attr=c(family="monospace"))
```

Comment: For something like a summary it might make sense to set `wrap=FALSE` in gtext too.

Comment: I was one step away from the solution but I just couldn't figure it out! Thank you so much for the help! @Dason 's suggestion of using `wrap=FALSE` is also very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use `glabel` for example:

```
win <- gwindow("Summary regression", visible=TRUE)
group <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=win)
obj <- glabel(as.character(summary(lm.D9)), 
         container=group, font.attr=list(style="bold"))
```

[image]

The result is not so beautiful, but I think it is a good start...

Comment: I also thought about this,using `gmessage`. But to make it pretty, I need to reproduce the `print.summary.****` function in a hard way. I just think there should be a better and clean way to go.